# Is there a way to tell if a PS2 will support YPbPr?

Tags: ps2

My TV (a JVC) has component input, labeled "Y Pb Pr" on the case.  I ordered a PS2, and the manual says that it supports "Y Cb/Pb Cr/Pr" (but doesn't mention "Y Pb Pr").

According to a review on AMZN, these are not the same thing, and the PS2 doesn't support "Y Pb Pr".  But according to other reports I've seen, even though a PS2 doesn't claim to support "Y Pb Pr", it works just fine with a component cable and a "Y Pb Pr" TV.

Are "Y Pb Pr" and "Y Cb/Pb Cr/Pr" the same thing?  And assuming they are not, is there any way to predict (from the model/serial number or such) whether my PS2 will work with a component cable with my TV?  I'm willing to pay a few bucks for better video quality, but if I know in advance it's a lost cause, I'd rather save the bucks.

Comment: In my experience you also need to see what the game supports. If you set your PS2 to progressive mode with the component cables and the game doesn't output in it, the video may blow up.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

YP<sub>B</sub>P<sub>R</sub> and Y P<sub>B</sub>/C<sub>B</sub> P<sub>R</sub>/C<sub>R</sub> are compatible: the slashes in the latter indicates it supports both YP<sub>B</sub>P<sub>R</sub> and YC<sub>B</sub>C<sub>R</sub>, which—for most intents and purposes—are the same thing.

The difference, if you're interested (from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YPbPr)):

> YP<sub>B</sub>P<sub>R</sub> is the analog version of the YC<sub>B</sub>C<sub>R</sub> color space; the two are numerically equivalent, but YP<sub>B</sub>P<sub>R</sub> is designed for use in analog systems whereas YC<sub>B</sub>C<sub>R</sub> is intended for digital video.

From the Wikipedia entry on [YC<sub>B</sub>C<sub>R</sub>](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/YCbCr):

> YC<sub>B</sub>C<sub>R</sub> is sometimes abbreviated to YCC. Y′C<sub>B</sub>C<sub>R</sub> is often called YP<sub>B</sub>P<sub>R</sub> when used for analog component video, although the term Y′C<sub>B</sub>C<sub>R</sub> is commonly used for both systems, with or without the prime.

Amazon is sometimes a wretched hive of scum and villainy: more often than not, reviews claim a problem is caused by a product when in fact it's caused by something unrelated but unbeknownst to the reviewer. Having had a PS2 hooked up to an analog and a digital TV over the lifespan of the PS2, I can confirm it supports both just fine.

Comment: I discovered that the back of my DVD player also says "Y Cb/Pb Cr/Pr", too, and it works fine with my TV, lending support to the idea that a "Y Cb/Pb Cr/Pr" PS2 should be just fine.